# Parse JSON array value as std::string using Boost

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to parse a std::string JSON string with this code:

```
        std::string ss = "{ \"id\" : \"abc123\", \"number\" : \"0123456789\", \"somelist\" : [{ \"timestamp\" : \"May 1, 2015\" , \"data\" : { \"description\" : \"some description\", \"value\" : \"100.000000\" } }] }";

        ptree pt2;
        std::istringstream is(ss);
        read_json(is, pt2);
        std::string _id = pt2.get<std::string>("id");
        std::string _number = pt2.get<std::string>("number");
        std::string _list = pt2.get<std::string>("somelist"); 


        for (auto& e : pt2.get_child("somelist")) {
            std::cout << "timestamp: " << e.second.get<std::string>("timestamp") << "\n";
            for (auto& e1 : pt2.get_child("data")){ // not working
                std::cout << "description: " << e1.second.get<std::string>("description") << "\n";
                std::cout << "value: " << e1.second.get<std::string>("amount") << "\n";
            }
        }
```

Although my target is not to print the child items (nor convert the JSON string into C++ array). The code above does not work.

I want to know how to get the value of `data` not as array or something, just as string like this `[{ "timestamp" : "May 1, 2015" , "data" : { "description" : "some description", "value" : "100.000000" } }]`

Just need the JSON Array as-is as std::string

Comment: Have you tried something like `std::stringstream ss; write_json(ss, pt2.get_child("data"));` ? In your case, `.get_child("somelist").get_child("data")` or `e.get_child("data")`.. depending where in your code you want to use it.

Comment: doing write_json(ss, pt2.get_child("data")); causes no such node error :-)

Comment: Huh? Just tried here and works as a charm. After  the printing timestamp and added those lines: `ptree d = e.second.get_child("data"); std::stringstream s1; write_json(s1, d); std::cout <<s1.str << std::endl;`. [Demo Link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f39ca70f6847cd9a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp` implements `write_json`, which is, as you would expect, the inverse of `read_json`. Since `ptree` stores arrays as objects with an empty key, to achieve the representation you want, you would loop over the top-level `ptree`s in `pt2.get_child("somelist")`, call `write_json` on each of them and format these representations as you wish.

```
for(auto const& node : pt2.get_child("somelist"))
 write_json(std::cout, node.second);
```

[Coliru Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17d1bdea3819b139).